# Subtraction with Values in an Array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I'm using an array to try to subtraction. However, when my script just gives me the total of my array with a negative sign in front of it. Any suggestions?

```
elif [ "$OP" = "Subtraction" ]; then
    echo "Please enter the number of values you would like to perform $OP"
    read num
        while [[ $num -gt $i ]]; do
            echo "Enter your value"
            read value
            let total=$total-$value
            let valuearr[$i]=$value
            let i=$i+1
        done
        echo "You entered ${valuearr[*]}, and asked me to perform $OP. The answer is $total."
```

Comment: What is the exact output that you get from this script fragment? If `total` is unset, you will get a negative sum if you enter positive values.

Comment: `$total` starts empty, so when you enter `1`, `2`, and `3`, your script computes `0 - 1 - 2 - 3`, which clearly is the same as `-(1 + 2 + 3)`.

Comment: What is the value of `$i` when this script fragment is entered? What about `$total`?

Answer (score 2):

If I set `i=1` and `total=0` before hand and change the test to `-ge` then it seems to work:

```
OP=Subtraction
if [ "$OP" = "Subtraction" ]; then
    echo "Please enter the number of values you would like to perform $OP"
    read num
    i=1
    total=0
        while [[ $num -ge $i ]]; do
            echo "Enter your value"
            read value
            let total=$total-$value
            let valuearr[$i]=$value
            let i=$i+1
        done
        echo "You entered ${valuearr[*]}, and asked me to perform $OP. The answer is $total."
fi

$ bash x
Please enter the number of values you would like to perform Subtraction
3
Enter your value
1
Enter your value
2
Enter your value
4
You entered 1 2 4, and asked me to perform Subtraction. The answer is -7.
```

By not setting `i=1` you'll miss one element of the `${valuearr[*]}` output.  `total=0` is just good code, in case the variable was used elsewhere.

Clearly 0-1-2-4 == -7 and so the result is correct.